# Not all arguments converted

Tags: python

In Python, I am getting **'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'**

I am not sure why this is happening. This line is being highlighted as where the problem lies - `data.append('%s,%s,%s'%line['code'],line['level'],line['target'],line['distancefromtarget']`

Can anybody find the problem?

In case it helps, here is the other code around this line.

```
def updatestocklevel(quantity, stocklevel, code):
        with open('stockcontrol.csv',newline='') as f:
                for line in f:
                    if code in line:
                        data = line.split(",")
                        target = (data[2])
        updatetarget = int(target) - int(stocklevel)
        newlevel = stocklevel - quantity
        stocklevel = str(stocklevel)
        newlevel = str(newlevel)
        updatetarget = str(updatetarget)
        import sys
        import csv

        data=[]
        code = code
        newval= newlevel
        newtlevel = updatetarget
        f=open("stockcontrol.csv")
        reader=csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=['code','level', 'target', 'distancefromtarget'])
        for line in reader:
          if line['code'] == code:
            line['level']= newval
            line['distancefromtarget']= newtlevel
          data.append('%s,%s,%s'%(line['code'],line['level'],line['target'],line['distancefromtarget']))
        f.close()

        f=open("stockcontrol.csv","w")
        f.write("\n".join(data))
        f.close()
```

Thank You.

Comment: did you tried debugging through `pdb`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. @NoobEditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a tuple with 4 elements:

```
(line['code'],line['level'],line['target'],line['distancefromtarget'])
```

But only 3 substitution placeholders:

```
'%s,%s,%s'
```

When you try to format that, not all of the "arguments" (tuple elements) will be converted to strings for the formatting (hence the error).  Either change the tuple to remove an element, or change the string being interpolated to add another field (e.g. `'%s,%s,%s,%s'`).

Comment: I thought it would be something obvious. Thanks.